# Plotting Number of Events that Occur in an Interval Histogram

Tags: excel, date, plot, data-analysis

In Excel, I have two fields per row, a start date/time and an end date/time.  I am looking to plot a histogram that shows how many of the rows' intervals contain the time on the x axis.

For example, some start and end times could be: [1,3], [3,4], [7,9], and [7,8]

And I want an output similar to:

```
    x       x x
x x x x     x x x
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split your tuples (say with Text to Columns) into say ColumnsA:B, starting in Row3 (say to Row6) and series filling D1:L9 (or to suit) with D1 = `1` and an integer increase.

Then in D3 copied across to L3 and D3:L3 copied down to Row6:

```
 =IF(AND(D$1>=$A3,D$1<=$B3),"X","")
```

and in D2 copied across to L2:

```
 =COUNTIF(D3:D6,"X")
```

Then make a column chart (INSERT > Charts) from D1:L2.

However, I may have misunderstood because there is no particular time significance to the above - the data is just treated like integers.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful.  Definitely a good solution for a histogram, which I will use.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a better way to implement this for continuous time instead of discrete.  Kind of like a stacked bar chart for a timeline but condensed into a density graph for usage.